# Why popover segue taking lot of time for the First time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I've an application where one HomeViewController triggers the popover segue so that destinationView controller may appear as a popover View controller. Everything is fine and destinationView Controllers is opening as popover View controller. 
But the problem is when I First touch the button, its taking lot of time to open destinationViewController. and later after that second touch onwards on its opening faster just on touch. why so ?

Comment: What is your destination view controller? It might perform a one time initialization that takes a lot of time.

Comment: Its just another View Controller. Whose size is freeform [300w, 900h]

Comment: As you don't provide any code one might only guess. The reason is probably your presenting view controller that performs something time consuming when disappearing and/or your presented view controller that does time consuming stuff when presented.

Answer (score 1):

The answer mostly lies in your code itself.

My guess is you are making some network call or data processing on main thread making UI responsiveness hit. You are probably caching the massaged data and using it second tap onwards.

You can fix this by putting break point and understanding the implementation line by line.